# C++ Compile Error (uninitialized in this function)

Tags: c++

I need help regarding to this message:

> cmd_general.cpp:3433: warning: 'safemode' may be used uninitialized in this function

Can somone explain what this error means?

This is the function:

```
ACMD(do_cards)
{
    const char *line;

    char arg1[256], arg2[256];

    line = two_arguments(argument, arg1, sizeof(arg1), arg2, sizeof(arg2));
    switch (LOWER(arg1[0]))
    {
        case 'o':   // open
            if (isdigit(*arg2))
            {
                DWORD safemode;
                str_to_number(safemode, arg2);
                ch->Cards_open(safemode);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You declare it without initializing and pass it to a function. As far as the compiler knows, you passed an uninitialized variable to two functions that may be expecting something with a real value so it warns you. Easy to fix, just initialize your variable.

Comment: It is very much possible that `safemode` is not assigned a value till it is being used in `str_to_number()`. And how are you managing you file with humongous `3k lines` of code ?

Comment: What's the type of `str_to_number`? And what is line 3433?

Comment: What's actually unclear about that error message? I've seen far worse ones.

Comment: I suspect `str_to_number` may take the argument by value rather than reference, guaranteeing it cannot be changed before being passed to the second function. That's just crystal ball though because this is not a complete example. Since you don't appear to be using the return value for error checking you might consider have `str_to_number` return the converted value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a variable of type `DWORD` without initializing it:

```
DWORD safemode;
```

Then you are passing it to a function:

```
str_to_number(safemode, arg2);
```

The compiler does not know that the initial value of the first argument is probably not used by the function, and therefore it is not a real issue here.

To resolve the warning, just initialize the variable with a default value:

```
DWORD safemode = 0;
```

Comment: Right. Tks very much.

Comment: Another solution would be to modify `str_to_number` to return the return value, instead of using the hack of "returning" via a reference parameter